# Xamarin Forms : Hide Editor or Entry underline

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using an editor in my UI. But the black underline is irritating, is there any way to remove that underline?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have done the entry and editor underline removal features using `custom renders`.

##In PCL##

**CustomEntry.cs**

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Entry_Editor_Sample
{
    public class CustomEntry : Entry
    {
    }
}
```

**CustomEditor.cs**

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Entry_Editor_Sample
{
    public class CustomEditor : Editor
    {
    }
}
```

##In android##

**CustomEntryRenderer.cs**

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.Res;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.Text;
using Entry_Editor_Sample;
using Entry_Editor_Sample.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEntry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]

namespace Entry_Editor_Sample.Droid
{
    class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        public CustomEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
                gd.SetColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
                this.Control.SetBackgroundDrawable(gd);
                this.Control.SetRawInputType(InputTypes.TextFlagNoSuggestions);
                //Control.SetHintTextColor(ColorStateList.ValueOf(global::Android.Graphics.Color.White));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomEditorRenderer.cs**

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.Res;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.Text;
using Entry_Editor_Sample;
using Entry_Editor_Sample.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEditor), typeof(CustomEditorRenderer))]

namespace Entry_Editor_Sample.Droid
{
    class CustomEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
    {
        public CustomEditorRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
                gd.SetColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
                this.Control.SetBackgroundDrawable(gd);
                this.Control.SetRawInputType(InputTypes.TextFlagNoSuggestions);
                //Control.SetHintTextColor(ColorStateList.ValueOf(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Black));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

##In IOS##

**CustomEntryRenderer.cs**

```
using Entry_Editor_Sample;
using Entry_Editor_Sample.iOS;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEntry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]

namespace Entry_Editor_Sample.iOS
{
    class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
                Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 10;
                //Control.TextColor = UIColor.Black;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomEditorRenderer.cs**

```
using Entry_Editor_Sample;
using Entry_Editor_Sample.iOS;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEditor), typeof(CustomEditorRenderer))]

namespace Entry_Editor_Sample.iOS
{
    class CustomEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
    {
        public CustomEditorRenderer()
        {
            UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillShow((sender, args) =>
            {
                if (Element != null)
                {
                    Element.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, args.FrameEnd.Height); //push the entry up to keyboard height when keyboard is activated
                }
            });

            UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillHide((sender, args) =>
            {
                if (Element != null)
                {
                    Element.Margin = new Thickness(0); //set the margins to zero when keyboard is dismissed
                }
            });
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 10;
                Control.TextColor = UIColor.Black;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

##Finally in MainPage.xaml##

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Entry_Editor_Sample"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             BackgroundColor="White"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
             x:Class="Entry_Editor_Sample.MainPage">

    <StackLayout
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        BackgroundColor="White">

        <local:CustomEntry
            BackgroundColor="SkyBlue"
            Placeholder="Entry"
            PlaceholderColor="Black"
            TextColor="Black"/>

        <local:CustomEditor
            BackgroundColor="SkyBlue"
            Placeholder="Editor"
            HeightRequest="100"
            PlaceholderColor="Black"
            TextColor="Black"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I uploaded a sample on [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/114646/hide-editor-underline#latest) :)

Comment: @DanielDolz Please comment the hint text color codes on the renderer. updated the answer also, please check.

Answer (score 8):

Create a custom renderer in your Android project:

```
public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer {
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e) {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        Control.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
    }
}
```

Then in your XAML:

```
<ContentPage xmlns:xyz="clr-namespace:PclNamespaceForCustomControls">
    ...
    <xyz:CustomEntry Placeholder="Lorem ipsum" />
</ContentPage>
```

See Microsoft docs for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry

Comment: Some of the damn cleanest code I've seen in years. I pasted this into my project just now and my product is now selling like hotcakes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [custom renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) to achieve entry and editor underline removal.
I am using the below code to apply these feature for all entries and editors in the project and it is working with Xamarin Forms 4.8+

## Xamarin Android

#### Entry

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(EntryRendererAndroid), new[] { typeof(VisualMarker.DefaultVisual) })]
namespace XFTest.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class EntryRendererAndroid : EntryRenderer
    {
        public EntryRendererAndroid(Context context) : base(context) { }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Background = null;
                Control.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Editor

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Editor), typeof(EditorRendererAndroid), new[] { typeof(VisualMarker.DefaultVisual) })]
namespace XFTest.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class EditorRendererAndroid : EditorRenderer
    {
        public EditorRendererAndroid(Context context) : base(context) { }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Background = null;
                Control.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Xamarin iOS

#### Entry

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(EntryRendereriOS), new[] { typeof(VisualMarker.DefaultVisual) })]
namespace XFTest.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class EntryRendereriOS : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromWhiteAlpha(1, 1);
                Control.Layer.BorderWidth = 0;
                Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Editor

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(EntryRendereriOS), new[] { typeof(VisualMarker.DefaultVisual) })]
namespace XFTest.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class EntryRendereriOS : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromWhiteAlpha(1, 1);
                Control.Layer.BorderWidth = 0;
                Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you find the answer is helpful, please mark it as accepted answer and vote it up and this will help other members.

Comment: I suggest not just to copy paste, your Editor renderer in iOS is a copy of your Entry renderer. BorderStyle does not apply to Editor.